# javascript binding other value to pressed key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind other value to the pressed keyCode
for example if the User presses `A` I want to display an Arabic Character `آ`
Is it possible in javascript ? as key is the readonly property of the event. Is there any extended version of Event which make it possible or any other idea?

Comment: You can simply catch the event, check the keyCode, and modify the element the event originated from to contain the different character.

Comment: Have you attempted this, do you have any code?

Comment: And use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the normal value from being inserted.

Comment: Yes, I have tried all as it is a contenteditable DIV which may contain many other HTML elements so this will not be possible to simply replace the content

Comment: @user1592129 not possible without changing the content.

Comment: How are you mapping Arabic characters to English characters? I am asking because Arabic characters will have a different key codes than English characters. If you are using an English Keyboard, it will return key codes specific to English characters. You need an Arabic keyboard, OR you need a translation service.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```js
document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
    if (event.key === 'e') {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        const [start, end] = [event.target.selectionStart, event.target.selectionEnd];
        event.target.setRangeText('آ', start, end, 'select');
        event.target.setSelectionRange(start+1, start+1);
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="demo"/>
```

Or for contenteditable:

```js
document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
    if (event.key === 'e') {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        const [start, end] = getCaretPosition(event.target);
        event.target.innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML.substring(0, start) + 'آ' +event.target.innerHTML.substring(end);
        positionCursor(event.target, start+1)
    }
});

function positionCursor(tag, pos) { 
    // Creates range object 
    var setpos = document.createRange(); 
    // Creates object for selection 
    var set = window.getSelection(); 
    // Set start position of range 
    setpos.setStart(tag.childNodes[0], pos); 
    // Collapse range within its boundary points 
    // Returns boolean 
    setpos.collapse(true); 
    // Remove all ranges set 
    set.removeAllRanges(); 
    // Add range with respect to range object. 
    set.addRange(setpos); 
    // Set cursor on focus 
    tag.focus(); 
}

// node_walk: walk the element tree, stop when func(node) returns false
function node_walk(node, func) {
  var result = func(node);
  for(node = node.firstChild; result !== false && node; node = node.nextSibling)
    result = node_walk(node, func);
  return result;
};

// getCaretPosition: return [start, end] as offsets to elem.textContent that
//   correspond to the selected portion of text
//   (if start == end, caret is at given position and no text is selected)
function getCaretPosition(elem) {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  var cum_length = [0, 0];

  if(sel.anchorNode == elem)
    cum_length = [sel.anchorOffset, sel.extentOffset];
  else {
    var nodes_to_find = [sel.anchorNode, sel.extentNode];
    if(!elem.contains(sel.anchorNode) || !elem.contains(sel.extentNode))
      return undefined;
    else {
      var found = [0,0];
      var i;
      node_walk(elem, function(node) {
        for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          if(node == nodes_to_find[i]) {
            found[i] = true;
            if(found[i == 0 ? 1 : 0])
              return false; // all done
          }
        }

        if(node.textContent && !node.firstChild) {
          for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if(!found[i])
              cum_length[i] += node.textContent.length;
          }
        }
      });
      cum_length[0] += sel.anchorOffset;
      cum_length[1] += sel.extentOffset;
    }
  }
  if(cum_length[0] <= cum_length[1])
    return cum_length;
  return [cum_length[1], cum_length[0]];
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable id="demo">Test</div>
```

Comment: hi dave thank you very much for your detailed response. I have a problem once I format some text in this editable area, the Cursor jumps always at the end of formatted block or start of the text

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague and missing examples at the moment, but you can achieve replacing of characters with a map rather simply, I hope this helps you

```js
var map = {
  "a": "b",
  // replace "a" characters when typed with "b"
};

var inputElement = document.querySelector("#input");

inputElement.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  
  var replacementCharacter = map[event.key];
   
  if (replacementCharacter){
    event.preventDefault();
    var cursorPosition = event.target.selectionStart;
    var originalValue = inputElement.value;
    var value = [originalValue.slice(0, cursorPosition), replacementCharacter, originalValue.slice(cursorPosition)].join("");
    inputElement.value = value;
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
```

Edit: I can see you're working with contentEditable, the solution shouldn't be much different, you need to update the innerHTML accordingly.

You may also want to add event `element.addEventListener("input", ...)` to detect pasting and other events that may change the content, to then mass-apply your mappings again.